# Folders for some Docker named volumes are empty?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a few Docker named volumes set up like this:

```
---
version: '3.8'
services:
  broker:
    ...
    volumes:
      - volume_kafka:/var/lib/kafka

  materialize:
    ...
    volumes:
      - volume_mzdata:/var/lib/mzdata

volumes:
  volume_kafka:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: /var/lib/kafka

  volume_mzdata:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: /var/lib/mzdata
```

When I go to `/var/lib/mzdata` on the host, it's the same as `/var/lib/mzdata` in the container. If I `docker-compose down`, then `docker-compose up`, everything in `/var/lib/mzdata` is the same as before.

However, `/var/lib/kafka` on host is missing all the files from `/var/lib/kafka` in the container. If I `docker-compose down`, then `docker-compose up`, some data is missing and there's a bunch of errors. It's not clear whether it reused `/var/lib/kafka` (but the files are invisible to me) or if it's storing the data elsewhere.

If the files on in `/var/lib/kafka` on the host, but it's invisible to me, how can I view them? `sudo` didn't work. If they're stored elsewhere, how can I find them?

Comment: Named volumes are only populated with the container's content of they are empty. Once there is something inside, they will override the container's file system. I'm talking about the behaviour when a container starts/ when the volume is mounted. After startup, the container can write to the volume and it will be stored, of course.

Comment: @TheFool I'm not sure what you mean, I tried deleting the Kafka volume and deleting `/var/lib/kafka` on the host. Docker recreates `/var/lib/kafka`, but it's missing all the files from the container

Comment: We don't know what image you're using to even know if `/var/lib/kafka` is the actual data directory for that image. If nothing is stored on your host, then it's completely possible the container doesn't use that path at all

Comment: That's may be either about the access rights, or about the mismatch of compose file's version. Also, take a look the default `/var/lib/docker/volumes` is there any were created.